# ListView - setOnItemLongClickListener not getting called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I tried various solutions mentioned in SO but still my issue is not resolved. Mentioned the code below.

Example.java

```
package com.android.Example;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import com.android.Example.db.Tbl_example_Title_DAO;
import com.Example.database.handler.example_Titles;
import com.android.Example.adapter.ArrayListAdapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Example extends Activity {
    Tbl_example_Title_DAO tbl_example_title;
    example_Titles example_Titles;
    ListView lvlist;
    List<String> exampleTitlesList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_singleitems_list);

        lvlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        tbl_example_title = new Tbl_example_Title_DAO(this);

        lvlist.setClickable(true);

        lvlist.setLongClickable(true);

        lvlist.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String s=exampleTitlesList.get(arg2);
                Log.w("HHHHHHHHHHHHHH", s);
                return true;
            }
        });



        showlist();
    }


    private void showlist() {
        example_Titles = new example_Titles();
        example_Titles.setexample("E");

        //List<example_Titles> exampleTitlesList = tbl_example_title.getTbl_example_Detailss(example_Titles);
         exampleTitlesList = tbl_example_title.getTbl_example_Details_str("E");
         Collections.sort(exampleTitlesList);   

        ArrayListAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayListAdapter(Example.this, exampleTitlesList); 
        lvlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }



}
```

listview_singleitems_list.xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="10dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Each row of the listview - amc.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/lvi"    
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    >
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tvCategory_listItem"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_margin="5dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Data is getting populated but not responding to any click events.

Kindly help me understand what i am missing in the code. Thanks

**Update 1 - Tried adding the below method. But Did not work.**

```
lvlist.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
          int position, long id) {
        final String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Log.w("HHHHHHHHHHHHHH", item);


      }

    });
```

**Update 2** - I Tried to use the below code and now the onclick works fine.So, **the issue is with the way i have created the amc.xml file only**. If anybody knows what is the issue, please let me know

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, categoryTitlesList);

         lvlist.setAdapter(adapter);
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

instead of

```
ArrayListAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayListAdapter(ExpenseCategoryList.this, categoryTitlesList);
lvlist.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 1):

get rid of these codes..

```
lvlist.setClickable(true);

lvlist.setLongClickable(true);
```

listview responds to item click and long click events.. so i could say it's a viewgroup..
but when you specify a listview to respond to click events like you've done you are telling the listview which is a view itself to respond to click events not its child..

and if you look at your code its

```
setOnItemLongClickListener or setOnItemClickListener respectively
```

not

```
setOnClickListener  or setOnLongClickListener
```

so test it and let me know if it helps

Comment: after clean rebuild and restart eclipse